# how to delete documents with some id in mongodb shanty library

Tags: php, zend-framework, mongodb

Could you please tell me why I can't delete from collection records with ids that are in the list using mongodb $in, but I can delete them if I use mongodb driver directly. Here ids are _id generated in mongodb automatically.
This one works:

```
array_walk($ids, function(&$item, $key) { $item = new MongoId(trim($item)); });

$conditions = array('_id' => array('$in' => $ids),
               );       

$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->test; 
$collection = $db->mycollection;
$result = $collection->remove($conditions, array('safe' => true));
```

But using method remove of class Shanty_Mongo_Document doesn't work for some reason with the same data:

```
class MyDocument extends Shanty_Mongo_Document
{

    public static function bulkDelete($ids)
    {

        array_walk($ids, function(&$item, $key) { $item = new MongoId(trim($item)); });

        $conditions = array('_id' => array('$in' => $ids)
                           );           
        $result = self::remove($conditions, array('safe' => true));
        return $result['n'];        
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I commented in source code of Collection.php in method remove:

```
/*        if (array_key_exists('_id', $criteria) && !($criteria["_id"] instanceof MongoId)) {
                $criteria["_id"] = new MongoId($criteria["_id"]);*/
```

After it conditions with $in work. Maybe the future versions of library will fix it.